How to preserve permissions when digitally signing an encrypted PDF file using iText Java?
I'd like to digitally sign an encrypted PDF file. The original PDF is protected by password that you can't modify it or copy texts from it without providing the owner's password. However, I found I can modify it and copy texts from it with ONLY user's password after stamping a digital signature! So, how do I correct the code to preserve permissions when signing the PDF? The code I used is showing below, where encryptPdf() is a method to encrypt PDF files and sign() is a method to sign the PDF files. I have wrote stampingProperties.preserveEncryption(); inside the  sign() method, but it still can't preserve permissions.
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

package net.opho.olympiad.util;
import com.itextpdf.bouncycastleconnector.BouncyCastleFactoryCreator;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.crypto.DigestAlgorithms;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.font.PdfFontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.mac.MacProperties;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.mac.MacProperties.MacDigestAlgorithm;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.*;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.PdfCanvas;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.xobject.PdfXObject;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.signatures.*;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import net.opho.olympiad.entity.PdfResource;
import net.opho.olympiad.entity.Signature;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
@Slf4j
public class PdfUtil {
    public static byte[] encryptPdf(String pdfPath, String userPassword, String ownerPassword) throws IOException {
        Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleFactoryCreator.getFactory().getProvider());
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        WriterProperties writerProperties = new WriterProperties();
        writerProperties.setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_2_0).setStandardEncryption(
                userPassword.getBytes(),
                ownerPassword.getBytes(),
                EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_256,
                new MacProperties(MacDigestAlgorithm.SHA_256));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfPath), new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream, writerProperties));
        pdfDocument.close();
        byte[] output = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        log.info(pdfPath + " encrypted, byte length: " + output.length);
        return output;
    }
    public static byte[] sign(byte[] pdfFileContent, String ownerPassword, Signature signature, String username) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfReader reader = ownerPassword == null ? new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfFileContent)) : new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfFileContent), (new ReaderProperties()).setPassword(ownerPassword.getBytes()));
        StampingProperties stampingProperties = new StampingProperties();
        stampingProperties.preserveEncryption();
        PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, byteArrayOutputStream, stampingProperties);
        SignerProperties signerProperties = new SignerProperties();
        signerProperties.setReason("Document for OPhO user " + username).setLocation("OPhO Official Website");
        signer.setSignerProperties(signerProperties);
        BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
        Security.addProvider(provider);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(signature.getKeyStorage()), signature.getKeyStoragePassword().toCharArray());
        String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, signature.getKeyStoragePassword().toCharArray());
        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName());
        IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        signer.signDetached(digest, pks, ks.getCertificateChain(alias), null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
        byte[] output = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        log.info("Signed, byte length: " + output.length);
        return output;
    }
}



"but it still can't preserve permissions." - How have you checked that?

@mkl before stamping the digital signature, I can't copy texts from the encrypted PDF file with only user's password (at least in Microsoft Edge PDF viewer). But I can do so after signing the PDF file.

Ok, so not by analyzing the files but by testing in PDF viewers. I'll try to reproduce. (But please be aware, @KJ is correctly implying that the actual permissions and non-permissions are only respected by cooperative software. Technically you have access to all the information in a PDF and can manipulate it arbitrarily whenever you have enough access to display it.)

@KJ "I "presume" iText has to run in "unethical" mode for edits such as ..." - I don't think so: If you supply the owner password, not just the user password, arbitrary changes  are allowed. Considering the parameter names used here, that is the case here, so no need for that official hack.

@mkl If I open an encrypted PDF file with user's password and remove the digital signature or use another key pair to resign the document without providing owner's password (maybe I need some non-Adobe software to do that unethically), will it cause MAC verification to fail? If so, I think encrypting a PDF file is still significant in such cases.

"If I open an encrypted PDF file with user's password and remove..." - as mentioned above, the user password suffices to apply arbitrary changes. In particular you have access to the underlying MAC key and can update the MAC to again be correct after your manipulation. In other words, the MAC is a protection against manipulations by users who don't have any password at all; anyone having a password (user or owner) can create a valid MAC.

Whilst permissions can be set on a PDF they are not needing to be used by viewers or other editors so usually they are preserved but not used.
I take this page and save with printing and copy denied. I then use a signing service that uses adobe methods. So most users would think that the encrypted file is "secured" but the reader can print and copy the text whilst showing those restrictions in its info.

Copied text

I'd like to digitally sign an encrypted PDF file. The original PDF is protected by password that
you can't modify it or copy texts from it without providing the owner's password. However, I
found I can modify it and copy texts from it with ONLY user's password after stamping a
digital signature! So, how do I correct the code to preserve permissions when signing the
PDF? The code I used is showing below, where
is a method to encrypt PDF files

Printing in action

Copy the signature (which is an image)

However none of those are possible in the Adobe application.

Without specifying the details. I can edit the text and replace the signature or even simpler remove it. It makes no difference if you use an "opener" password, as that is still handing the keys over to unlock the file, but adds a falser sense of security (for a second or two)  and your life is too short as it is.
